# volume entropy and Hausdoff dimension

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, hausdorff-dimension

In relation to this question: [Relation between volume entropy and Hausdorff dim of limit set?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131004/relation-between-volume-entropy-and-hausdorff-dim-of-limit-set)

Given a metric space $Z$ and a hyperbolic approximation $X := hyp_{r_0}(Z)$ (as defined for example [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=Lao2mfi9bNUC&lpg=PA69&ots=chu6cheNbP&dq=%22hyperbolic%20approximation%22%20schroeder&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

I noticed the following correspondence (for $x_0 \in X$):

$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{1}{r} \log_{1/r_0}(vol(B_r(x_0))) = \dim_H(Z).$$

Is this generally true? Does this follow from the answer in the linked question?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: This follows directly from Mesures de Patterson-Sullivan sur le bord d'un espace hyperbolique au sens de Gromov by Michel Coornaert
(https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102634263):

If we define
$$e_a(\Gamma) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \#\{g \in \Gamma : l(g) \leq n\}}{n \log a}$$

Then we have: $\dim_H(\partial \Gamma) = e_a(\Gamma)$ where $a = \frac{1}{r_0}$.